# C# Expression Trees and is null

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I am trying to create an expression tree to make a lambda that can be used in an EntityFramework Where clause. I need to check for null and am trying to use `is null`. So something like this:

```
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "data");
    var fieldExpression = Expression.Property(param, "Address");
    var nullTest = Expression.IsNull(fieldExpression);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(nullTest, param);
    var compiled = lambda.Compile() as Func<Customer, bool>;

    using dbContext = new TestDbContext();
    var customersWithNullAddress = dbContext.Customers.Where(compiled);
```

Here assuming that the `dbContext` has a `DbSet<Customer>` and `Customer` has a property called `Address`. The goal is to have this:

```
    var customersWithNullAddress = dbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.Address is null);
```

but I need to dynamically generate the predicate since it is coming from a user interface that allows the user to create the filter condition dynamically.

Of course this doesn't work because `Expression.IsNull` doesn't exist. I can't seem to find some mechanism to do this in expression trees. I guess I can do

```
    Expression.Equal(fieldExpression, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(Address))
```

But that doesn't seem like the recommended way to test null anymore, and I want to be sure it translates into the correct SQL as `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Address is null`

Anyone able to do this pattern matching in expression trees?

Comment: `== null` already converts to the correct `is null` in SQL, so just use `Expression.Equal` as you've shown in question.

Comment: Also, "But that doesn't seem like the recommended way to test null anymore" is quite arguable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `is null` operation in C# is syntactic sugar that was added long after LINQ expression trees were created. In regular code it compiles to the same IL code (for most cases at least) as `== null`, so there's not much incentive to add the syntax to expression trees at this point.

As to how it converts to SQL, `== null` has always converted to `IS NULL` in SQL since the good old LinqToSQL days. There may still be a few ways to get some SQL conversions to result in `= NULL` - which is of course always false - but you have to really try to invoke one of those.

So if you're just looking for assurance that the literal `something == null` will always translate to `something IS NULL` in SQL for EF (or LinqToSQL, or NHibernate, or Linq2DB, or...), you've got it. Too much code would break badly if it didn't work that way.